# How to add sonar scanner in GoCD?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, go-cd

I am creating a GoCD pipeline to run sonar analysis for my project. Up to now, I have successfully configured sonar properties on my local file and it successfully pushes the metrics to the sonar server.

The problem occurs when creating a GoCD pipeline to run the analysis. I am unable to successfully install sonar scanner on GoCD agents. The error that I get when executing command sonar scanner from the pipeline is "SONAR_RUNNER_HOME does not point to a valid installation directory".

Comment: Is it possible to set SONAR_RUNNER_HOME as an environment variable?

Comment: What I did was the same. I added SONAR_RUNNER_HOME environment variable to the GoCD pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently We are running sonar-scanner from GoCD pipeline and checking SonarQube Quality Gates correctly.

What we do was the following: I created a bash script that launch the sonar-scanner. This script (and other ones used by our GoCD configuation) is inside a second Git Material (the first one is the Project source code). We have installed the 'SonarQube Quality Gates Task Plugin' to evaluate our SonarQube quality gates.

So we have a Job in our Pipeline with the following tasks:

1. **Type:** Custom Command --- **Run if:** Passed --- **Command:** /bin/bash
   --- **Arguments:** path_to_sonar_scanner_bash_script_launcher.sh --- **Working Directory:** your_working_dir
2. **Type:** SonarQube - Quality Gate --- **Run if:**
       Passed --- **Key of the SonarQube project:** sonar_qube_project_id ---
       **Fail Quality Gate result:** error Sonar --- **Api Url:**
       http://your_sonar:9000/api

We have GoCD agent and sonarqube installed in the same machine.

I expect this  help you.